# How to not return success when data is not valid, or exception is thrown?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using jQuery Ajax, and I hit the `success: function (msg)...`. I want to be able to specify when to hit: `error: function (msg)...`

The issue here seems to be that I don't have a way to return `true` or `false`, since I have to return a View. In a normal web app (unlike mvc), I used to just return true or false, then I could check on this boolean value, and act according to this.

How can I specify that I want to jump to the `error: function (msg)` in some cases? For example when the validation doesn't pass, I don't want it to say it's a success.
Here is my JQuery code:

```
function ContactDialog(action, controller) {    
var url = '/' + action + '/' + controller;

$("#ContactDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    hide: "fade",
    show: "bounce",
    height: $(window).height() / 2,
    width: $(window).width() / 2,
    title: "Send an email",
    buttons: [{
        text: "Send", click: function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,                                     
                data: $("form").serialize(),
                context: this,
                contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (msg) {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    sendConfirmMessage('msgSent');                        
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    sendConfirmMessage('msgNotSent');
                }
            });
        },
    }, {
        text: "Cancel", click: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }]
});
```

}
And my html code that does the validation:

```
 <div id="ContactDialog" style="display: none;">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(null, null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "UpdaterDiv" }, new { id = "contactForm" }))
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.subject)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.subject, new { @class = "AboutControls" })
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.subject)
        <br />
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.from)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.from, new { @class = "AboutControls" })
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.from)
        <br />
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.body)
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.body, new { @class = "AboutControls AboutControlTxtArea" })
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.body)
        <hr />
        <br /><br />
    }
</div>
```

Here is the code where I am forced to return a View:

```
public PartialViewResult SendMail(EmailModel model)
        {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    mailMsg = new MailMessage(model.from, receiver, model.subject, model.body);
                    smtp.Send(mailMsg);

                    return PartialView("_About");
                }...
```

The jQuery Ajax code has no way of knowing when it is a success or failure from the above code, since I can't say `return true` or `return false`
Hope I am making myself clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MVC controller action do the following:

```
var status = new HttpStatusCode();

if(DataIsInvalid) //whatever validation you need to perform
{
   status = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
}
// any other validation

return new HttpStatusCodeResult(status);
```

If you need to change it back so it doesn't trigger the `error` in your AJAX, either leave `status` null or set it to `HttpStatusCode.OK`

Comment: Thanks, I will try that when I get to my Visual studio. But I see you are returning someting that is not a View. Won't the compiler complain about that?

Comment: I know it works when I am returning an `ActionResult` from my MVC controller, hopefully it works with yours.

Comment: Sweet. It does not work if the type is PartialViewResult, but I changed the type to ActionResult, since the two seem to act the same upon returning a PartialView. So it works :D